# ASP.NET web application: 404 error in the remote server when a common database connection string is used

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, http-status-code-404, connection-string, remote-server

I'm working with a project in c# asp.net..
When i created individual connection strings for accessing the database, the program runs properly in the local and remote servers..
But when i wrote the connection string commonly in a class and accessing those connection using an object, it works properly in the local server but while running in the remote server it shows a "404 error"..
Please help..

Comment: Show us some code. There may be something wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you create database in your server ?? and are you deploy all pages in your server ???

check below links

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315122

Comment: Yes, i created the db in server.. and transferred all files to the server using FileZilla..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like a remote server problem in general than anything specific in your code. Are there other ASP.NET pages or sites already running on the remote server successfully? If not, it may be related to the way you've deployed the site than your code - are you sure IIS is set up to serve the ASP.NET site correctly?

I'd start by creating a "test.aspx" page with no dynamic content and try accessing that, and then work forward from there.

Comment: the .aspx file which do not have connection string is running fine with the remote server.. There is no DB connetion code in Default.aspx(starting page). so its running properly.. the problem is with the page that's having the common connection string for accessing DB..